# What's OT in this answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, off-topic

[A question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/56915/1485) I asked about the yoke force necessary to counteract whatever may drive a B737 MAX 8 into the ground was put on hold as OT. During a mod interaction references to flight JT610 (which obviously inspires the question) were removed, and the mod canceled a close vote they had apparently cast.

A little later a sufficient number of readers voted to put the question on hold as OT.

While the question as it now stands may be confused and layman-like (what now? Autopilot? "Systems"?) it does not appear OT to me. It is a technical question about an airplane feature and its handling and as such perfectly on topic.

What am I supposed to do now? I'm genuinely interested in technical answers. This is clearly not speculation about what actually happened on that doomed flight (even though it may constructively *inform* such speculation, elsewhere), which understandably *would* be OT.

If anybody wants to improve the question don't hesitate.

(P.S. I just see that I got a Popular Question Badge for that question. I think it was on the "Hot" list. I don't seem to be the only one finding it interesting.)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. When a question that was closed is edited to bring it on-topic (or to remedy whatever reason it was closed), it is automatically placed in the *reopen queue*. Users with close-vote privileges can look at the question, check that the problems have been fixed, and vote to either leave it closed or reopen it.

The reopen queue is always short, so if the question is truly on-topic now, it's only a matter of time until enough people vote to reopen it.

Comment: The closing happened after the editing (and after the moderator I interacted with canceled their close vote); I didn't make that clear, I see.